# Reusing a menu with PHP and dir, but href is not clickable

Tags: php, path

I'm trying to make a menu that I can reuse. I have diffrent views in different paths, thats the reason I want to use the **DIR**. Only my solution doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem. Or is there an other solution to reuse a menu?

**Map structure**

```
-Movie
 -Add.php 
-View 
 -Template
  -Menu.php
Index.php
```

**menu.php**

```html
    <header>
        <a href="<?= __DIR__ . '/../../'; ?>" class="header-item">
            Films
        </a>

        <a href="<?= __DIR__ . '/../../movie/add.php'; ?>" class="header-item">
            Voeg film toe
        </a>
    </header>
```

**index.php**

```
<?PHP
include 'controller/MovieController.php';
$movieController = new MovieController;
$movies = $movieController->getMovies();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="resources/css/general.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="resources/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <?PHP require_once 'view/template/menu.php' ?>

    <main>

        <div class="films">
            <?PHP
            if ($movies) :
                foreach ($movies as $movie) :
            ?>

            <a class="film" href="movie/movie.php?movie=<?= htmlspecialchars($movie['id']) ?>">
                <img src="<?= htmlspecialchars($movie['images']) ?>">
                <h1><?= htmlspecialchars($movie['name']) ?></h1>
            </a>

            <?PHP
                endforeach;
            endif;
            ?>
        </div>

    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

**html output**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="resources/css/general.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="resources/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

        <header>
        <a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\php-challenges\movie\view\template/../../" class="header-item">
            Films
        </a>

        <a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\php-challenges\movie\view\template/../../movie/add.php" class="header-item">
            Voeg film toe
        </a>
    </header>
    <main>

        <div class="films">
            
            <a class="film" href="movie/movie.php?movie=2">
                <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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">
                <h1>Minion 5</h1>
            </a>

            
            <a class="film" href="movie/movie.php?movie=5">
                <img src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/iNhLypShzO1fBXUzQjAOZzmiBTnamR5k_4M74Qf4ZOmK4t3ETm_HNjGfinUj2fYpIz5JsocJh6e1UroOKanC=s256-rw">
                <h1>Sonic</h1>
            </a>

            
            <a class="film" href="movie/movie.php?movie=8">
                <img src="https://cdn.pocket-lint.com/r/s/1200x630/assets/images/159643-tv-news-spider-man-no-way-home-image1-dryautoefj.jpg">
                <h1>Spiderman 2</h1>
            </a>

                    </div>

    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

When I hover over the menu with my mouse I get these link in my left corner.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Z5O.png)

Comment: what’s the actual html output sent to the browser?

Comment: @Psi I added the html output to my original question

Comment: first of all, your backslashes in the path are wrong, at least they’re not escaped. second, there are no html elements called „header“ and „main“. third, a file resource pointing to a local destination may be considered a security risk by your browser and therefore ignored in an http context.

Comment: I also tested it online, but it didn't work there either. : https://www.maxkik.nl/movie/index.php

Comment: You're not being super clear about what the problem is. Are the links in the rendered HTML not what you expected? How are they different? Are you confusing local file paths with URLs?

Comment: @miken32 
I only want to create the menu once and then use it on multiple pages. I added the map structure to my question.


When I use the menu in index.php with require_once then the path from menu.php is different than when I use the menu from movie/add.php. That's what I'm trying to solve with __DIR__, but I don't know if that's the right solution.

Comment: @mike32 Like when you use asset() in Laravel.

Comment: So you are confusing file paths with URLs. Simplest method would be to define a variable with the relative URL path in index.php and then use it in menu.php, or inspect the URL and adjust accordingly. But there's no super simple way to write your own view manager.

Comment: @mike23 thank you. I'm going to delve into the difference between urls and file paths and I'm going to make a solution with a function and an array.